# Serial UART Mode reverts to RS232 on boot

Tags: serial-port

I'm using a Moxa Linux unit, Debian 9, and the port0 mode needs to be set to mode 1, 2 wire RS485. I use a startup script instigated via crontab which does work as the associated app restarts, but the mode resets every time to mode 0, RS 232. This is the script, any thoughts?

If I set the port mode manually, it works fine, but always goes back to mode 0!

This is the specific line that should work:

```
mx-uart-ctl -p 0 -m 1
```

Comment: You mention the scripts, but it is not included in the question. Also, what is the exact crontab entry?

Comment: The script appears to be missing from your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im trying to attach the files!

Comment: This is the script. It starts the ./CoreApp ok, so Im happy the crontab is instigation the script.

Comment: #File path to WaveView Connect
wvcpath="/home/moxa/WVC"
$wvcpath/CoreApp


#setting serial port 0 mode 
sudo mx-uart-ctl -p 0 -m 1
#set serial port 0 baud rate
#stty 4800 -F /dev/ttyM0
#set serial port 1 mode 
#mx-uart-ctl -p 1 -m 0
#set serial port 1 baud rate
#stty 9600 -F /dev/ttyM1

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on crontab and create log file and here is what I got:

```
Set uart mode failed
```

Look like crontab has run before some initial service which mx-uart-ctl depend on.
I decided to run mx-uart-ctl command as a system service.
Here is my config file

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable RS485 2-W Mode
After=uc2100-base-system.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/moxa/rs485.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may have to change After parameter up to your system (networking.service may also work)

And here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
mx-uart-ctl -p 0 -m 1
```

Note: if the script not working, try to add /sbin (or directory contain mx-uart-ctl) to your path. If you afraid that add /sbin to your path may impact on security or some thing else, you can create a symlink to directory in you path like this `sudo ln -s /sbin/mx-uart-ctl /usr/local/bin/`